# Взаимодействие между JDBC и БД R-Keeper

Tags: java, jdbc

Подскажет пожалуйста. Может кто работал с R-Keeper. Возможно ли в JDBC подключится к БД R-Keeper?

Спасибо.

Comment: Я не нашел JDBC для R-Keeper, если хотите, можете написать свою реализацию

Comment: @RomanDanilov мне вообще интересно возможно ли такое. Ибо говорят что есть трудности с работой с ним ибо R-Keeper закрытая система